# How to give the input layer in Layers array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, octave, matlab-guide

I am trying to build a Neural Network in Matlab that does dropout on the hidden layer using the inbuilt `dropoutLayer`. So the code is as follows:

```
layers = [
    fullyConnectedLayer(hidden_layer_nodes(1))
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(hidden_layer_nodes(2))
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(hidden_layer_nodes(3))
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(output_layer_size)
    regressionLayer
    ];
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in main (line 54)
net = trainNetwork(X,y,layers,options);

Caused by:
    Network: Missing input layer. The network must have one input layer.
    Layer 1: Missing input. Each layer input must be connected to the output of another layer.
```

which I understand because I haven't given an Input Layer in the layers array. But I am unsure what InputLayer I should give, as the Input is not an image nor a sequence and list of available input layers are:

1) imageInputLayer

2) image3dInputLayer

3) sequenceInputLayer

4) roiInputLayer
taken from the official Matlab Docs.

Please let me know what alternative I can use other than defining my own layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who has faced the same issue and is coming over to StackOverflow for help, check the below link posted on the MathWorks community. This actually seems to be working for non-image and a non-sequence input.

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/395817-can-i-use-trainnetwork-to-train-deep-neural-networks-with-non-image-or-non-sequence-data-for-regre

This explains a way by which you can use the imageInputLayer to input any kind of data in the Layers array.